# How the game sends force feedback to the steering wheel

Tags: game-design, controllers

How the game will be some of the information feedback to the steering wheel, such as bumps, bumps, vibration and so on. View MSDN, which are introduced from the steering wheel to get the relevant information and control the steering wheel of the force feedback, but how to get from the game inside the type of force feedback?

Comment: What do you mean with "type of force feedback"? Do you mean how it rumbles?

Comment: How to know the current situation of the vehicle, such as collision, bumps and so on

Answer (score 1):

> how to get from the game inside the type of force feedback

This is a game design question.

Once you know what feedback features are available for the controller in use, whether it is a game controller with a rumble pack, or a steering wheel with force feedback, you need to decide what you will do with it.

What will you transfer from the game universe back to the players hands?

Depending on the answer, you'll add some code that will map in-game events to controller feedback events.

For instance, if you want to make the steering wheel harder to manipulate (increasing the force feedback), you can try and detect the following events in your game:

- Powersteering failure (this will be an event that you'll decide to generate)
- The player is taking a sharp turn at a high velocity (you can inspect the current requested steering angle, along with the current linear velocity of the vehicle; combine these to find how hard will it be to steer).

Or if you have a controller with a rumble pack, and you want to detect the bumps, you'll have to inspect the vertical velocity of the wheels: if it gets above a certain threshold, you send a short rumble signal to the controller.

In any case, it will require the programmer and the designer to work together: one to implement the feature, and the other to tune it.

There is no magic to it: plan, code, tune. And there is more than one way to achieve what you need. This will depend on your game and your engine.